# Error while passing an angular argument in a function call inside ng-click directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I am a rookie in AngularJS. I am building a corporate dashboard. I have two views - Dashboard and Profiles. In Profiles I have multiple profile details which I am rendering using ng-repeat and the JSON is also present inside the profiles controller. Whenever a user clicks on one of the profile I want to redirect it to that profile's dashboard.

Now, inside the ng-repeat:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="data in epc.employees" class="empCard md-whiteframe-4dp" >
```

I am using ng-click like this:

```
<a ui-sref="dashboard"><md-button ng-click="loadGraphs({{data.id}})">View Dashboard</md-button></a>
```

The loadGraphs function is defined independently in another JS sheet and is used to manipulate the C3.js Charts. Now, whenever I click on the button I get redirected to dashboard with the following error:

```
angular.js:10347 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 8 of the expression [check({{data.id}})] starting at [{data.id}})].
```

I have also tried:
 `<a ui-sref="dashboard"><md-button ng-click="loadGraphs(data.id)">View Dashboard</md-button></a>`

In this case there is no error but the function is not being called while redirecting to dashboard.
Please help.

Comment: You don't need to bracket the argument of `loadGraphs`.

Comment: I've tried without brackets too. In that case there are no errors but the function is still not being called.

Comment: Need more information to see what's going on. Can you post the relevant controller code and html?

Comment: Actually loadGraphs is defined in another js file which contains the c3.js code as I have to modify the graphs according to the id passed. So on clicking I am modifying the graph data displaying in dashboard  according to the id passed while simultaneously redirecting to dashboard view.The loadGraph function is defined  independant of the controller because I am calling it from other views also. It is not defined inside the profile controller.

Comment: Angular generally plays nice with other javascript frameworks, but you need to play by Angular's rules. In this case, because you are calling the function from `ng-click` the browser is looking for `loadGraphs` in the `angular` namespace. I'm not familiar with` c3`, but i think you'll need to inject the `c3` object into the controller and wrap that object's `callGraph` with a function that can be called from `ng-click` using data that exists in the `angular` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in ng-click you dont need to use brackets:

```
<md-button ng-click="loadGraphs(data.id)">View Dashboard</md-button>
```

If you still get error, check if there is no typo in your function names and if you are using the same scopes (controllers). I recomend you checking some angular tutorials.